# How to make an HTML element which is otherwise sequential and static float with the page when past a particular height?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have a `<section></section>` that is somewhere down the page. When a user gets to the point where the section is off the page, I want the section to float statically at the top of the screen and always be at the top when the user is below where the section would normally statically reside.

I am using Angular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to know exactly what you mean without a code example but you could always use `position: sticky`

https://jsfiddle.net/2d5r0sux/

Comment: sticky without `top`, `left`, `right`, `bottom` is just same as `realtive`